# How do I assign EntityCollection property to another property?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

I have a type that is derived from an Entity generated by the Entity Framework 3. How do I assign one Customer's Order property to the Derived Customer's Order property?

```
derivedCustomer.Orders = customer.Orders
```

I'm not actually trying to swap orders; this is just an example of what I am trying to achieve. Has anyone done tried this and succeed?

Comment: Are you getting an exception or...?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each record and add to the other collection:

```
foreach (var order in customer.Orders)
   derivedCustomer.Orders.Add(order);
```

You could make an extension method to make that seamless too.